# How to detect if a device is connected to a laravel server?

Tags: android, laravel

I'm using laravel as the back-end web and have created API to communicate with the android device. Everything is working fine, now **I want to detect if the device is connected with the server or not?**

I'm sending the device status `1` on the login and `0` on the logout/close, but I'm facing one problem, once the internet connection closed on the device I'm not able to send any message on the server side.

So I want to know any way that can help me to detect that the internet is closed and device is disconnected. **I can detect the internet closed state on the android side, but I can't send the message to the server**.

How I can solve this?

Comment: This sounds like you need to look at websockets. The good news is that there is a lovely package that allows you to host a websocket server from the laravel app. With Websockets you can then trigger an event on the channel disconnect that changes that device status from 1 to 0.  This is a great YouTUbe playlist on Websockets and video 7 & 8 is about setting up your own Pusher server replacement. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO9rlj-U9oOi4m2sQaWN6XA8

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because for sending message to server you need internet and without internet, it's not possible.

Perhaps some response time variable can help you. like we do with session. 
In session we set default time, if the user did not interact within the default time we expect user to disconnect or leave the webpage and we destroy his session.

the same kind of thing you can use in this scenario if the user did not interact for let's say 20 min with the application, Assume the user is disconnected